# removing all things Google Map (api) to meet GDPR-Compliance

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

running the theme Jobify: https://astoundify.com/products/jobify/
this includes some google-maps that means it fetches the maps from google-Api. This may cause some GDPR issues for lots of user in the world.

**solution:** we tried to find a solution that takes away the google-assets from the page - completly!!

now - we can come up with one - which is not verified yet:

Just in case anybody is interested in an answer  i guess that we can do this like so:
To remove Google Maps from the Jobify theme completely, we can try this steps and  follow these ones: Go to the WordPress dashboard and navigate to the "Appearance" section.

Click on "Editor" to access the theme files.

Open the "functions.php" file.

Locate the code that initializes the Google Maps API. It should look something like this:

```
php
Copy code
function jobify_google_maps_api() {
wp_register_script( 'google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY', array(), null, false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jobify_google_maps_api' );
```

Comment out or delete this code to disable the Google Maps API.

Save the changes to the file.

This should remove Google Maps from the Jobify theme completely.
However, keep in mind that removing this functionality may affect other parts of the theme, so we may need to make additional changes or modifications to ensure the theme still works as intended.

Well i want to share this just in case anybody is interested in an answer  i guess that we can do this like so:

**note:** This change will be undone when the theme updates

To make this happen in a way that will not go away on update you can create a child theme or a custom plugin and use

```
remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jobify_google_maps_api' );
```

to prevent the map from loading

**btw:** see also: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219049/remove-extra-google-maps-script

Comment: Well done. But this isn't really a question, is it?
You could check this: https://stackexchange.com/sites# to find another Stack Exchange environment where you can place the code.

Comment: good day dear Erwin - many thanks for the reply. Good comment - food for thoughts. 
Well i do so. well if so then we can regard this as solved. Thanks to you - btw.- what should i do now - i do not want to infringe the board rules.!? Plz advice me

Comment: Hi Malaga, Don't mind the board rules too much. ;-) Thing got too strict in here anyway lately.
If you, as owner of the question, don't see a close-button, just leave it as it it. No worries

Comment: many thanks for the quick reply - glad to hear from y ou - i can with the question - edit and things like that. Hope fully this thing ( this question ) wont kill my account here. 

many many greetings to the netherlands ;) have a great day.